# mergesort C implementation

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

i wrote this code in C language on Xcode following the algorithm of mergesort.
The problem is that sometimes i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS and i can't manage where the error is!
The merge algorithm should work (i tried it outside the mergesort function and works!). Thank you for your help and patience!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define DIM 6

void mymerge (int v[], int i1,int i2, int last); //mergesort core: merge two ordinated arrays in one bigger ordinated array
void mymergesort (int v[], int lower, int upper);//mergesort
void printv (int v[],int lower, int upper);

int main () {
    int i;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int v[DIM];
    for (i=0; i<DIM; i++)
        v[i]=rand()%15;
    printv(v, 0, DIM-1);
    getc(stdin);
    mymergesort(v, 0, DIM-1);
    printv(v, 0, DIM-1);
}
void printv (int v[],int lower, int upper){
    int i;
    for (i=lower; i<=upper; i++)
    printf("%d\t",v[i]);
}
void mymergesort (int v[], int lower, int upper){
    int mid=(upper+lower)/2;
    if (upper<lower) {
        mymergesort(v, lower, mid);
        mymergesort(v, mid+1, upper);
        mymerge(v,lower,mid+1,upper);
    }
}
void mymerge (int v[], int i1,int i2, int last){
    int i=i1,j=i2,k=i1,*vout;
    vout=(int*)malloc((last-i1+1)*sizeof(int));
    while (i<i2 && j<=last) {
        if (v[i]<=v[j]) {
            vout[k++]=v[i++];
        }else {
            vout[k++]=v[j++];
        }
    }
    for (;i<i2;i++) vout[k++]=v[i];
    for (;j<=last;j++) vout[k++]=v[j];
    for (k=i1; k<=last; k++) v[k]=vout[k];
free(vout);
}
```

EDIT:
thank you very much! but i think think there is another problem, when I try to sort a bigger array (200 elements), the program doesn't work (i get a malloc error: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed). But if I run it from the xCode debugger everything works fine

Comment: can you format the code properly?

Comment: I do not think that formatting came out correct. Try again? This time use the code tag.
Also you may want to mark this as homework. People will help more then.

Comment: sorry i didn't managed how to format the code! i don't mark it has homework because it isn't :D it's just for free time... :D

Comment: open the code in your editor, extend your indention out to 3 spaces and then re-paste.

Comment: @user: why did you indent it with only one space? It's like it's not indented at all..

Comment: My apologies, it looked like homework.

Comment: @Jeff: it still looks like homework :)

Comment: it's not homework mates... it's personal pleasure :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This: `vout=(int*)malloc((last-i1)*sizeof(int));` is wrong.

First, the number of elements you want is `last-i1+1`, not `last-i1` - classic off-by-1. This kind of error is one of the reasons why the convention in C code is to make lower bounds inclusive and upper bounds exclusive - less `+1` and `-1` you need to do, less opportunity to screw up.

The more serious error is that you index `vout` starting from `i1`. If you do it this way, you need to allocate `last+1` element for `vout`, and you never use the first `i1` (index 0 .. `i1-1`).

Fix: First, allocate `last-i1+1` elements. Second, initialize `k` to 0 at the beginning, not `i1`. Third, change the final copy to be

```
for (k=i1; k<=last; k++) v[k] = vout[k-i1];
```

Comment: thank you very much! but i think think there is another problem, when I try to sort a bigger array (200 elements), the program doesn't work (i get a malloc error: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed). But if I run it from the xCode debugger everything works fine.

Comment: `valgrind` is your friend there.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.  The first is that your calculation of the midpoint is incorrect - you use `(upper - lower)/ 2`, but this is not guaranteed to lie between `lower` and `upper`.  What you actually want is `lower + (upper - lower) / 2`.  It's also not necessary to do any work if there's only 1 number in the interval to be sorted - so the `mymergesort()` function should look like:

```
void mymergesort (int v[], int lower, int upper)
{
    if (upper > lower) {
        int mid = lower + (upper - lower)/2;

        mymergesort(v, lower, mid);
        mymergesort(v, mid+1, upper);
        mymerge(v,lower,mid+1,upper);
    }
}
```

The second problem is the one in the `mymerge()` function already pointed out by [Fabian Giesen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361909/mergesort-c-implementation/4362020#4362020).

Comment: mid should be calculated as :
int mid = lower + (upper - lower)/2;
//prevents overflow

Comment: @siddhusingh: Yes, that is preferable.

Comment: mymerge(v,lower,mid+1,upper); must be mymerge(v,lower,mid,upper);

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void merge(int *a, int n1, int *b, int n2, int *arr)
{
  int i=0, j=0, n=0;
  while(i<n1 && j<n2)
  {
    if (a[i] < b[j])
    {
      arr[n++] = a[i];
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
      arr[n++] = b[j];
      j++;
    }
  }
  while( i < n1)
    arr[n++] = a[i++]; 
  while( j < n2)
    arr[n++] = b[j++];
}
void merge_sort(int *a, int n)
{
  int left[n/2], right[n-n/2],i=0;
  if (n<=1)
    return ;
  while(i<n/2)
    left[i] = a[i++];
  while(i<n)
    right[i - n/2] = a[i++];
  merge_sort( left, n/2 );
  merge_sort( right, n-n/2);
  merge(left, n/2, right, n-n/2, a);
}  
void main()
{
  int a[] = { 6, 5, 3, 1,9, 8, 7, 2, 4},i;
  merge_sort(a,sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
  for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    printf("--%d",a[i]);
  printf("\n");
}


-- s.k
```

Comment: This would segfault, where did `arr` come from?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define max 20
/*** function  for merging the adjecent subarrays in sorted order ***/
void merge(int A[max],int n,int low,int high, int mid)
{
     int i=low,j=mid+1,k,temp;
     while((i<=j)&&(j<=high))     
     {
        if(A[i]>A[j])          /** if element of the second half is greater then exchg and shift **/
        {
           temp=A[j];
          for(k=j;k>i;k--)    /** shifting the elements **/
           {
             A[k]=A[k-1]; 
           }
           A[i]=temp;
           j++;
        }
        i++;
     }
}
/******* iterative function for merge sort ********/
void merge_sort(int A[max],int n,int low,int high)
{
     int mid;
     if(low<high)                     /** terminating condition  **/
     {
        mid=(high+low)/2;            /** calculating the mid point ***/
        merge_sort(A,n,low,mid);     /*** recursive call for left half of the array ***/
        merge_sort(A,n,mid+1,high);  /*** recursive call for right half of the array ***/
        merge(A,n,low,high,mid);    /** merging the both parts of the array **/
     }
}
/******* begening of the main function **********/
int main()
{
    int A[max],n,i;
    /** reading the inputs fro  users **/
    printf("\n enter the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n enter the array \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       scanf("%d",&A[i]);                 
    }
    /*** calling merge sort ***/
    merge_sort(A,n,0,n-1);
    /** printing the sorted array **/
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       printf("\n\t%d",A[i]);                 
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```